# Error (10500): VHDL syntax errors in quartus (VHDL)

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl, quartus

So this is a hw assignment in VHDL. We are comparing the first 2 bits and last 2 bits of a 4 bit binary number and when the first two are greater than the last two it should output a 1 to gt. However, I'm getting 2 errors and I have no clue how to fix them. We aren't using a process statement for this assignment.

```
----------------------------------
--Written by K Moore
--HW 2
--9/8/2021
-----------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
--import libraries

entity HW_two is
   port (a1    :in std_logic;
         a0    :in std_logic;
         b1    :in std_logic;
         b0    :in std_logic;
         gt    :out std_logic);
end HW_two;

--Unsimplified equation
 --A1'A0B1'B0'+ A1A0'B1'B0' + A1A0'B1'B0 + A1A0B1'B0' + A1A0B1'B0 + A1A0B1B0' = gt
--Simplified equation => gt= A0B1' + A0B1'B0' + A1A0B0'


architecture compare of HW_two is

begin
   gt <= (a1 not and a0 and b1 not and b0 not) or (a1 and a0 not and b1 not and b0 not) or (a1 and a0 not and b1 not and b0) or
   (a1 and a0 and b1 not and b0 not) or (a1 and a0 and b1 not and b0) or (a1 and a0 and b1 and b0 not);
    
end compare;
```

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at hw_two_kmoore.vhd(28) near text
> "not";  expecting ")", or ","
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at hw_two_kmoore.vhd(29) near text
> "not";  expecting ")", or ","

Comment: Not is a unary logical operator. In VHDL's unary operators are prefix operators. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.2 Logical operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `not and` operator. `not` expects a value to the right of it.
Acceptable logic operators are:

- not
- and
- or
- xor
- nand
- nor
- xnor